# Is MFA required for extraction automation job using DataLoader

Tags: mfa

Looking at the Login Types that will be affected, for Data Loader, we have an automated process  that uses Data Loader to extract various object / field level data out of Salesforce on a daily basis. If MFA is going to apply to use of Data Loader and this is an automated process, does that mean that the extraction job will stop working? Is there anything that we can do to fix it or as for automated process MFA is not required we can leave MFA untouched.

Comment: Have you checked the resources on the [MFA Getting Started](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trailblazer-community/groups/0F93A000000DQQHSA4?tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC#discussion) group?

Answer (score 1):

No, API-based integrations will not require MFA. This means that client software such as the Data Loader (when *not* using OAuth-based login flows) will not require MFA.

Comment: And to make API based integration which ever user is used to connect just go to profile of that user and go to Administrative Permissions and check the API Enabled box. Alternatively you can add a permission set for it as well.